# man: hide help message

Tags: colors, man, less

I have set high contrast color for "search results" in man:

```
export LESS_TERMCAP_so=$(tput setaf 1; tput setab 3)
```

so that my search results are highlighted and easy to find. Unfortunately, this color is used for the useless help message at the bottom, which says:

```
Manual page ls(1) line 6 (press h for help or q to quit)
```

Is it possible to hide this help message? I really don't find it useful. I am capable of remembering `h` and `q` commands.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two options here.

**1.** You can set the `MANLESS` environment variable to what ever you need:

```
export MANLESS=" "
```

**2.** You can add the `-r` option to your `man` command:

```
man -r="" ls
```

Both possibilities are described in the `man` manual page.